# Auto-increment in Oracle table when insert in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence

I have a table and I want to increment a column by 1 when I insert a row into the same table.

Table `users` - when I insert first row value of `idusers` is `1`, and in second row value is `2` ....

This is the table

**USERS**

```
    EMAIL primary key
    USERNAME
    PASSWORD
    IDUSER and this the column I want to be AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I have tried this code

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_person
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10;


create or replace trigger incrementIdUser
    before insert on users
    for each row
    begin
        select seq_person.nextval into :new.IDUSER from users;
    end;
```

But I get an error when I insert a row:

> Erreur lors de l'enregistrement des modifications de la table "SOCIAL"."USERS" :
> Ligne 1 : ORA-01403: no data found
> ORA-01403: no data found
> ORA-06512: at "SOCIAL.INCREMENTIDUSER", line 2
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SOCIAL.INCREMENTIDUSER'
> ORA-06512: at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insetead of `select seq_person.nextval into :new.IDUSER from users;` to assign sequence value into iduser you need to use  `:new.IDUSER :=seq_person.nextval;`

```
create or replace trigger incrementIdUser
    before insert on users
    for each row
    begin
         :new.IDUSER :=seq_person.nextval;
    end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not like that, but

```
create or replace trigger incrementIdUser
  before insert on users
  for each row
begin
    :new.iduser := seq_person.nextval;
end;
```

---

Code you wrote selects from `users` table (which is empty, hence `NO_DATA_FOUND`). If it contained more than a single row, you'd get `TOO_MANY_ROWS` (as you're selecting into a scalar *variable* (`:new.iduser`). Finally, there's danger of *mutating table* error as you can't select from a table which is just being modified (in this trigger type).

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because there are zero rows in the `USERS` table so `SELECT ... FROM USERS` returns no rows.

What you want is to either use a table that will always return a single row (which, in Oracle, is the `DUAL` table):

```sql
create or replace trigger incrementIdUser
    before insert on users
    for each row
    begin
        select seq_person.nextval into :new.IDUSER from DUAL;
    end;
```

Or, the better solution, is to not use an SQL statement and use pure PL/SQL:

```sql
create or replace trigger incrementIdUser
    before insert on users
    for each row
    begin
        :new.IDUSER := seq_person.nextval;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a trigger, you should use an identity column in the create table statement:

```
create table users
(iduser integer generated by default on null as identity (nomaxvalue nocache order),
 ...);
```